# How to get data slice in matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, data-structures, slice

I want to take slices of data from the "MatrixEgoNetwork" matrix with "MatrixIndirectNode", but here I find difficulties, can you help me?

I tried to use retainAll() but I still couldn't

```
   public double countSimilarity(double[][] matrixEgoNetwork, double[][] matrixIndirectNode, int index) {

    if (matrixIndirectNode == null) {
        return this.countDirectSimilarity(matrixEgoNetwork, index);
    }

    double sim = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixEgoNetwork.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixEgoNetwork[0].length ; j++) {
            matrixEgoNetwork[i][j].retainAll(matrixIndirectNode[i][index]) //"I tried to Use retainAll() but an error appeared Cannot resolve method"
            if (matrixEgoNetwork[i][0] ==  matrixEgoNetwork[i][index] && matrixEgoNetwork[i][j]!=0) {
                sim++;

        }
        }
  }
return sim;

    }

private double countDirectSimilarity(double[][] matrixEgoNetwork, int index) {
    double sim = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixEgoNetwork.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixEgoNetwork[0].length ; j++) {
            if (matrixEgoNetwork[i][0]== matrixEgoNetwork[i][index] && matrixEgoNetwork[i][j]!=0) {
                sim++;

            }
        }

    }

    return sim;

}
```

the output I want to produce is the amount of data obtained from the slice between the matrices, the error is Cannot resolve method when i use a retainAll to get data slice between the matrix, can you help me fix that?

Comment: Please elaborate your problem. That would be helpful

Comment: I have edited it again, thanks for the advice sir,

Comment: Okay, the `retainAll()` is a method of `Collection`. So to do that, you need to convert your matrix to an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>`

Comment: `retainAll` is present on `Collection` interface. Are you trying to keep in MatrixEgoNetwork all elements present in MatrixIndirectNode? Do they have to have same value and same position or are you treating both matrices as collections and as long as element X exists in the second matrix, it should be kept in the first one?

Comment: I will only save the data between the 2 matrices, and the data will be stored in the sim attribute sir